Is there a way to way to add to a list from multiple threads with only one atomic variable write?
I know you can either:

Lock mutex, write data, unlock mutex.
Set atomic flag, write data, unset atomic flag.

Is there a way of doing this with only one atomic write? I'm thinking maybe a linked list where the pointer is an atomic variable or something? It's not possible to do with a dynamic array of contiguous memory, right?

Concurrent lists are typically linked lists.  Adding an element to a linked list requires modifying two pointers. You can either do this with a mutex (simple) or using extremely clever programs.  But you need more than one write.
